# Excel 2010 adding to an adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to add B3 to C3 leaving the answer in C3, I have tried =C3+B3 in C3, a message regarding circular references, I continue and the result becomes a zero

Comment: basically excel doesn't support calculations in the way you described them. Generally either a cell contains a value (constant), either a formula and it displays the result of the calculation. The way you've described is called iterative calculation and you can find information on it just by searching the internet. However there will be a couple of questions: if you change B3, then it should be added to the original or actual value of C3? Should it be added again during a recalculation? If you describe your situation better (and explain why you can't just calculate in D3) we can help more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that a calculation in Excel is meant to be continuously calculated but you're wanting to treat it as a one-time calculator. In this case, I would probably suggest just adding another column or use another cell somewhere else on the sheet to calculate your final result.